# How to retrieve URL dynamically?

Tags: vbscript

I am using a webservice in my project. I am giving URL like this:

```
WebServicename.asmx/Methodname
```

Locally I used webservice in VBScript and it is running good. But when I deployed same code in a server the webservice is not running. So before that webservice I want to give full URL. So for that reason I want to get that URL dynamically and add before of my URL.

Comment: I doubt very much this is VBScript I think you mean VB.Net

Answer (score 0):

I am writing Vb script and I call webservice like this

Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")

```
    Set oXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    'Msgbox("Calling WebService To Approve Leave")

    strEnvelope ="varCarrierType="&varCarrierType &varCarrierID& "&Filename="&Filename& "&varC22Cnt="&varC22Cnt&"&varCurrentDateTime="&varCurrentDateTime&"&varTotalCommissionAmt="&varTotalCommissionAmt&"&vpath="&vpath

    oXMLHTTP.onreadystatechange = getRef("HandleStateChange")

    call oXMLHTTP.open("POST","/VBScriptService.asmx/InsertDBDetails",False)

    call oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    call oXMLHTTP.send(strEnvelope)
    MsgBox "COM File successfully generated from the Template given. Verify the output file in " & vpath,0, "Com File Generation"


    MsgBox "Page About to Refresh, Click ok to proceed", 0, "ComPage Refresh"
    Set wShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wShell.SendKeys "{F5}"
```